# PHP file isn't parsed and responds with application/x-httpd-php instead of JSON

Tags: php, apache, ckfinder

Firstly, all of the code **does** parse and works as expected except this one file.

The file is connector.php from CKFinder V3 that is meant to be responding with JSON but instead is returning the PHP code. The response:

```
<?php

/*
 * CKFinder
 * ========
 * http://cksource.com/ckfinder
 * Copyright (c) 2007-2016, CKSource - Frederico Knabben. All rights reserved.
 *
 * The software, this file and its contents are subject to the CKFinder
 * License. Please read the license.txt file before using, installing, copying,
 * modifying or distribute this file or part of its contents. The contents of
 * this file is part of the Source Code of CKFinder.
 */

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

use CKSource\CKFinder\CKFinder;

$ckfinder = new CKFinder(__DIR__ . '/../../../config.php');

$ckfinder->run();
```

An example of what it should respond with is:

```
{"enabled":true,"s":"","c":"F799H8BWZTL","thumbs":["150x150","300x300","500x500"],"images":{"max":"2000x2000","sizes":{"small":"480x320","medium":"600x480","large":"800x600"}},"resourceTypes":[{"name":"Files","allowedExtensions":"7z,aiff,asf,avi,bmp,csv,doc,docx,fla,flv,gif,gz,gzip,jpeg,jpg,mid,mov,mp3,mp4,mpc,mpeg,mpg,ods,odt,pdf,png,ppt,pptx,pxd,qt,ram,rar,rm,rmi,rmvb,rtf,sdc,sitd,swf,sxc,sxw,tar,tgz,tif,tiff,txt,vsd,wav,wma,wmv,xls,xlsx,zip","deniedExtensions":"","hash":"31062ffc66943ba7","acl":1023,"maxSize":2097152,"hasChildren":false,"url":"\/uploads\/files\/"},{"name":"Images","allowedExtensions":"bmp,gif,jpeg,jpg,png","deniedExtensions":"","hash":"8bca000aae25ed21","acl":1023,"maxSize":2097152,"hasChildren":true,"url":"\/uploads\/images\/"}],"uploadMaxSize":2097152,"uploadCheckImages":false}
```

I don't know why this particular file doesn't want to play ball.

Chrome dev tools has the response header as `content-type: application/x-httpd-php` I don't see any other file with that content-type. All the other pages that work have `content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8` but none of those end with `.php` as they're rewritten with mod_rewrite, if it matters.

The permissions on connector.php are the same as a site (different server) that does work. `root:root 644`

I've looked at a lot of the similar questions with AddHandler and AddType.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

and

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php   php
```

I've implemented those in .htaccess and php.ini with no effect.

The server is a Docker box running apache `Apache/2.4.10 (Debian)` and PHP `7.1.27`

I am happy to provide `phpinfo()` output,  Dockerfile, .htaccess whatever helps.. just let me know the relevant sections.

Comment: is the php apache module installed?

Comment: @NickMaroulis yes. I mentioned everything else does parse. I just found the problem. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 0):

Sonofa... spend hours head butting walls, post, 2 minutes later find it.

Docker file had:

```
echo "  <LocationMatch assets/>"; \
echo "    php_flag engine off"; \
echo "  </LocationMatch>"; \
```

Full URL to file:
    https://dev.site.com/cms/modules/app/assets/js/ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=Init&lang=en&id=foo

Comment: That link doesn't go anywhere.

Comment: @tadman of course it doesn't.. it's an example showing how locationMatch matched the assets segment in it and killed parsing.

Comment: I'm not sure what utility that link as as it doesn't seem to help anyone understand this better. Maybe including just the `connector.php?...` part would make sense.

Comment: @tadman maybe you're not understanding the contents of the answer. The LocationMatch block turns the php engine off for a segment with assets in it. The link to the file shows there is an "assets" part to it and forces the "php engine" off. This is why this one file was not being parsed when all others were, PHP was told not to due to assets being in the path. I'm not sure how I can make it clearer. I can't mark it as the answer.